# CollapsingToolBarLayout with TabLayout and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: Layout example from app]

Am try to create a layout similar to the one in the image using a CordinatorLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout, TabLayout and ViewPager.
My Layout doesn't render properly.

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/movie_tabs"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:paddingStart="20dp"
                app:paddingEnd="20dp">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/movieviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Testing it on my device i get this
[image][image]

The ViewPager Fragment overlays the TabLayout if it has content and displays the TabLayout on top of the ImageView when there is no content.
What am i doing wrong, i am still somewhat of an Android noob.

Answer (score 4):

1. `CollapsingToolbarLayout` needs a `minHeight`. This tells the parent `AppBarLayout` how much it can collapse. I assume you want the `Toolbar` and the `TabLayout` to stay at the top of the screen (because you are using the `exitUntilCollapsed` scroll flag). I would make both of those have `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` and use double that value as the `minHeight` of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
2. `ViewPager` needs `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

Answer (score 3):

Old answer but maybe someone found it useful

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


<!--            Your extra details excluding tablayout. if u want any..-->
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context="com.sweedesi.android.customerapp.Fragments.SweetMartListFragment">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/home_dummy_4"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/black_shadow"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    tools:context="com.sweedesi.android.customerapp.Fragments.SweetMartListFragment">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_reviews"
                                android:text="Bhagat Mishthan Bhandar"
                                android:textColor="@color/orangeColor"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_slarge"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_reviews"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                                android:text="580 reviews"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_normal" />


                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:background="@color/orangeColor" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/min_order"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_normal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_price"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                                android:text="1000"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_normal" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                                android:background="@drawable/location_white" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                                android:text="Bhati enclave, Main queens road, Opp Jharkhand mahadev mandir, Vaishali nagar, Jaipur - 302021"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_normal" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orangeColor"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabText"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorText" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/transperentColor"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Best is to use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.ehryourway.ehryourway.PatientChart"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_patient_chart">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        android:layout_below="@id/tablayout">
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```